# PHP Exception message thrown with different charset

Tags: php, exception, character-encoding, redis

I use utf-8 for default charset. It is set in both in PHP.ini and header. I require the [Redisent](https://github.com/jdp/redisent) library and catch exception it throws. And when I display an error message it is always in Windows-1251 (it's windows default russian cyrillic charset). I tried to save Redisent's source file Redis.php in UTF-8 but it doesn't help.

Comment: I know nothing about the library but it appears to get strings from sockets. Is the Redis server supposed to generate UTF-8?

Comment: You could try convert encoding to utf-8 using `mb_convert_encoding()` or `iconv()`